# Nested table rows are not getting cloned using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form in my webpage and the form consists of a table which in return has a nested table in it. when I try to clone the rows of the nested table, the rows are not getting cloned. However the cloning works fine for the outer table. Here is my HTML code

```
<html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>

        <body>
        <div id="division">
            <form class="allergyrow">
                <table id="tab" border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Remove</th>
                            <th scope="col">Allergy</th>
                            <th scope="col">Reaction</th>
                            <th scope="col">Adverse Event Date</th>
                            <th scope="col">Comment</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="datarow">
                            <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "remove" class="remove" value = "Remove" /></td>
                            <td><input type = "text" id = "myText" class="myText" /></td>
                            <td >
                                <div>
                                <table id="inner" class="inner">
                                <tbody>
                                <tr id="innerrow" class="innerrow">
                                <td>
                                <select id = "myList" class="myList">
                                <option value = "1">Rashes</option>
                                <option value = "2">Shock</option>
                                <option value = "3">Asthma</option>
                                <option value = "4">Nausea</option>
                                <option value = "5">Anemia</option>
                                <option value = "6">Unknown/Other</option>
                                </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <select id = "reaction" class="reaction">
                                <option>Yes</option>
                                <option>Mild</option>
                                <option>Moderate</option>
                                <option>severe</option>
                                </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <button id="plus" class="plus">plus</button>
                                </td>
                                </tr>

                                </tbody>                            
                                </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="date" id="eventdate" class="eventdate"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="comment"  class="comment"/></td>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
```

Here is my Jquery code which I am using to clone the innertable rows

```
 $("#plus").click(function(){
            var row=$("#innerrow");
            row.clone().appendTo("#inner");
            s
         });
```

but the JQuery code doesn't seem to be working, when I debug I can see that the cloned rows are being created and then they disappear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**ID's** are supposed to be unique. When the code works , you will be left multiple `tr's` with the same id. Try using a class instead

Also you seem to be using the `button` which is the id of the button that is not unique. You need to replace that with a class as well.

The main problem here is you need to **delegate the events.**  Events are only bound to elements that are available in the DOM when event handler is associated. But in your case your cloned element is not present when this happens.

Replace the code with and make sure you remove the id's for the elements that you think will be cloned.

```
$("#inner").on('click', '.plus', function (e) {
    e.preventDeafault(); // Also need to call this to prevent form submission
    var row = $(".innerrow").first();
    row.clone().appendTo("#inner");
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/8evnd/)**

Comment: Instead of delegation you could just use `.clone(true)`

Comment: @Zenith.. Right.. you can use that as well.. That would also attach the events and data associated with the cloned data. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: I removed all the id's and replaced the onclick function with your code Sushanth. I still have the same problem, when I debug to walk through the code I see that the cloned rows are being created and the control goes to the Jquery-1.8.2.js library function and when the control returns the cloned row disappears. Thanks

Comment: Looks like it is working in the fiddle.. Can you show the code that you tried

Comment: Sushanth, never mind I mixed up the buttons I applied this functionality to the submit function. My mistake, the code is working. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: glad to have helped :) . Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/8evnd/1/

Answer (score 0):

In a HTML document, you can't have two elements with same ID. An ID must be unique.
So it's possible that clone() doesn't work because of that, you can't have two identical IDs